# Is it possible to set ExpansionPanelList in stateless widget?

Tags: dart, flutter

Is it possible to set ExpansionPanelList in stateless widget ?
I can't make it because in statelesswidget we can't setstate, so my expansion panel list won't expand

Comment: Have you tried to use any kind of scope management? Like providers, scoped model, bloc, etc?